# How to structure a proper 3-tier (no ORM) web project

Tags: 3-tier

I m working on a legacy web project, so there is no ORM(EF,Nhibernate) available here. 
The problem here is I feel the structure is tedious while implementing a new function.

let's say I have biz Object Team.
Now if I want to get GetTeamDetailsByOrganisation
,following current coding style in the project,I need:

1. In Team's DAL, creat a method GetTeamDetailsByOrganisation
2. Create a method GetTeamDetailsByOrganisation in the Biz Object Team, and call the DAL method which I just created
3. In Team's BAL, wrap up the Biz object Team's method in another method,maybe same name, GetTeamDetailsByOrganisation
4. Page controller class call the BAL method.

It just feels not right. Any good practice or pattern can solve my problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I know the tedium you speak of from similarily (probably worse) structured projects. Obviously there are multiple sensible answers to this problem, but it all depends upon your constraints and goals.

If the project is primarily in maintenance mode with very no new features being added I might accept that is the way things are.  Although it sounds like you are adding at least some new features.

Is it possible to use a code generator?  A project I worked on had a lot of tedium like this, which apparently was caused because they originally used a code generator for the code base which was lost to the sands of time.  I ended up recreating the template which saved me a lot of time, sanity, and defects.

If the project is still under active development maybe it makes sense to perform some sort of large architectural change.  My current project is currently in this category.  We're decoupling code and adding repositories as we go.  It's a slow process that takes diligence and discipline by the whole dev team.  Each time a team takes on a story they tax that story with rewriting some of the legacy code in that area.  To help facilitate this we gave a presentation to the rest of the team to get buy-in and understanding.  We also created some documentation for our dev team that lists out the steps to take and the things to watch out for.  In the past 6 months we've made a ton of progress.  We don't have the duplication you speak of, but we have tight coupling issues which makes unit testing impossible without this refactor.

This is less likely to fit your scenario, but it may also be a possibility to take certain subset of features and separate those out into separate services that can be rewritten using a better platform and patterns.  The old codebase can interoperate at the service layer if needed. You likely make changes in certain areas more than others, so the areas of heavy change might be top priority to move to a dedicated service.  This has the benefit of allowing you to create a modern code base without having to rewrite the *entire* application from scratch all at once.  This strategy is what Netflix has done to rewrite their their platform as they go and move it to the cloud.

Comment: Thanks @Sneal, the project i m working on is a mantenance one, so will add some features but not a lot. So refactor may not be a good choice to me. What I really want to know is how to make a archetecture in such kind senerio well. Your experience like seperate biz into dedicated service layer is helpful but still seems a bit abstract. You mentioned u did some presentation, is it possiable passing them(ppt) to internet? then I may get more solid idea, how to get things done in a smart way in future.